# Probability to draw equal number of red and green marbles

Tags: combinatorics

From an urn containing equal number of red and green marbles, we draw an even number of marbles. Prove that the probability of drawing an equal number of marbles from each color is $\frac{2}{\sqrt{n\pi}}$.

I am not sure: I think that the probability is $$\frac{\sum_{k = 2}^{n} C(k, k/2)}{\sum C(n, k)}$$ where k is even. 
Then by Stirling's approximation, we have $C(2k, k)= \frac{4^k}{\sqrt{k\pi}}$?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig Thanks for editing my question. I will do, thank you.

Comment: The problem is formulated in an absolutely **lousy** way. What is $n$, and what is $k$ in your attempted solution? Are the drawn marbles replaced or not? If we are drawing $2$ marbles from $4$, with or without replacement, the probability in question will be a rational number.

Answer (score 0):

I think the intended interpretation is that $n$ relates to the number of marbles you draw, not the total number, and the total number of marbles is much larger (so that you can approximate by assuming individual marbles are independent; an alternative interpretation which also works is that the marbles are drawn *with replacement*).

I think they want you to take $n$ to be the even number we draw; then the probability of drawing exactly $n/2$ of each colour is about $\binom{n}{n/2}2^{-n}$.

(Could there be a mistake in the answer given above? I get $\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$, and I can't find an interpretation that gives the extra factor of $\sqrt 2$.)

Comment: Thanks. I agree with your formula. Then how do we arrive to my result \frac{2}{\sqrt{n\pi}}? I think we are missing a "2".

Comment: Yes, sorry, I started with $n$ marbles drawn and found I was missing a $\sqrt 2$ so thought I had to draw $2n$ marbles. But actually that makes the problem worse!

Comment: Maybe we do not divide by \2^{n} but with the total number of ways to pick an even number of marbles out of n. This is the sum of the even terms of the binomial, which is equal to 2^(n-1)-1 (sorry, I tried wring it with the mathematics typeset but failed :(